# How can I draw a arrow for showing incoming/ outgoing calls

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I'm creating an app that shows Call Log.

In most of the contacts app we see arrows representing incoming/outgoing/missed calls.

where can I get them or can I create them using drawables or something?

Comment: I don't know the particulars of your application, but can you use an icon (one for incoming, another for outgoing)?

Comment: see `android.R.drawable.sym_call_*`

Comment: Check this [link](https://icons8.com/web-app/for/all/incoming%20call). Here just type the name of icon that you want and it will give you desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You can install and use this plugin - [Android Material Design Icon Generator](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7647-android-material-design-icon-generator) - in Android Studio. It has a collection of several icons. It will also automatically put different sizes of drawables in their respective drawable folders.

To install a plugin in Android Studio: Goto settings/preferences -> plugins -> browse repositories.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about icons, you can try [Google Material Icons](https://material.io/icons/). It is the standard library of icons recommended by Google.

Answer (score 0):

https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html

I got those icons from this website.I think this is very good website to make new icons